# Why am I getting Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(datatype mismatch) though everything seems perfect?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am using an API,to fetch data and display it in a list view after some constraints.I am fetching the data from the API ,it is printing as well and getting stored as well.But still I am getting Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(datatype mismatch),though I checked the order in which I have put them down in correct.I am really fed up with this JSON parsing.It is a real pain actually speaking.

Below is the list of dart files I have used in my flutter project:

This is my main file,where I will be displaying the data in a list view:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'services.dart';
import 'db_provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(Main());

class Main extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainState createState() => _MainState();
}

class _MainState extends State<Main> {

  var isLoading = false;

  _loadFromApi() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    var apiProvider = Services();
    await apiProvider.getAllCustomers();


    // wait for 2 seconds to simulate loading of data
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }


 Widget _buildEmployeeListView() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: DBProvider.db.getAllCustomers(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else {
          return ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                Divider(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                ),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: Text(
                  "${index + 1}",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
                title: Text(
                    "Name: ${snapshot.data[index].name}  "),
                subtitle: Text('status: ${snapshot.data[index].status}'),
              );
            },
          );
        }

      },
    );
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadFromApi();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Customer details'),
        ),
        body: _buildEmployeeListView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is my JSON data:

```
{
  "list":[
    {
      "id":"MnJJA0dbuw",
      "name":"Anand Sharma",
      "img":"https://incablet-tests.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/conference-content/photos/sponsors/Anand.jpeg",
      "gender":"m",
      "age":46,
      "date":"23/11/2019",
      "status":"onboarded"
    },
    {
      "id":"MnZmmmbuw",
      "name":"Malashri Lal",
      "img":"https://incablet-tests.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/conference-content/photos/sponsors/Vishesh.jpg",
      "gender":"f",
      "age":70,
      "date":"01/10/2019",
      "status":"active"
    },
    {
      "id":"MnZy10dpsq",
      "name":"Suhasini Haidar",
      "img":"https://incablet-tests.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/conference-content/photos/sponsors/Suhasini.jpg",
      "gender":"f",
      "age":30,
      "date":"23/03/2019",
      "status":"left"
    },
    {
      "id":"HOnmFt5jA",
      "name":"Vishesh Mahajan",
      "img":"https://incablet-tests.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/conference-content/photos/sponsors/Vishesh.jpg",
      "gender":"m",
      "age":34,
      "date":"05/05/2019",
      "status":"active"
    },
    {
      "id":"MnZy10dxyz",
      "name":"Anand Neelakantan",
      "img":"https://incablet-tests.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/conference-content/photos/sponsors/Anand.jpeg",
      "gender":"m",
      "age":46,
      "date":"03/10/2019",
      "status":"left"
    },
    {
      "id":"MnZy1JJbuw",
      "name":"Malashri",
      "img":"https://incablet-tests.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/conference-content/photos/sponsors/Malashri.jpg",
      "gender":"f",
      "age":65,
      "date":"04/01/2019",
      "status":"active"
    },
    {
      "id":"JKAS10dbuw",
      "name":"Meenakshi Madhavan",
      "img":"https://incablet-tests.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/conference-content/photos/sponsors/Meenakshi.jpg",
      "gender":"f",
      "age":35,
      "date":"01/03/2020",
      "status":"left"
    },
    {
      "id":"sOw8c6BOug",
      "name":"Fintan",
      "img":"https://incablet-tests.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/conference-content/photos/sponsors/Fintan.jpg",
      "gender":"m",
      "age":55,
      "date":"09/12/2019",
      "status":"onboarded"
    },
    {
      "id":"MnZy10dlll",
      "name":"Jaishree Periwal",
      "img":"https://incablet-tests.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/conference-content/photos/sponsors/Jaishree.jpg",
      "gender":"f",
      "age":50,
      "date":"01/02/2020",
      "status":"active"
    },
    {
      "id":"KbN3VELflA",
      "name":"Anukriti Upadhyay",
      "img":"https://incablet-tests.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/conference-content/photos/sponsors/Anukriti.jpg",
      "gender":"f",
      "age":30,
      "date":"31/01/2020",
      "status":"onboarded"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the PODO file I have created:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final customerInfo = customerInfoFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

CustomerInfo customerInfoFromJson(String str) => CustomerInfo.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String customerInfoToJson(CustomerInfo data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class CustomerInfo {
  CustomerInfo({
    this.list,
  });

  List<ListElement> list;

  factory CustomerInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CustomerInfo(
    list: List<ListElement>.from(json["list"].map((x) => ListElement.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "list": List<dynamic>.from(list.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class ListElement {
  ListElement({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.img,
    this.gender,
    this.age,
    this.date,
    this.status,
  });

  String id;
  String name;
  String img;
  Gender gender;
  int age;
  String date;
  Status status;

  factory ListElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ListElement(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    img: json["img"],
    gender: genderValues.map[json["gender"]],
    age: json["age"],
    date: json["date"],
    status: statusValues.map[json["status"]],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "img": img,
    "gender": genderValues.reverse[gender],
    "age": age,
    "date": date,
    "status": statusValues.reverse[status],
  };
}

enum Gender { M, F }

final genderValues = EnumValues({
  "f": Gender.F,
  "m": Gender.M
});

enum Status { ONBOARDED, ACTIVE, LEFT }

final statusValues = EnumValues({
  "active": Status.ACTIVE,
  "left": Status.LEFT,
  "onboarded": Status.ONBOARDED
});

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

Below is the db provider I have created to store the data.I need to still write the SQL command to properly get the data in the required sorting order.For the time being it is Select *

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'podo_file.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

//9-22   creating a Database object and instantiating it if not initialized.
class DBProvider {
  static Database _database;
  static final DBProvider db = DBProvider._();

  DBProvider._();

  Future<Database> get database async {
    // If database exists, return database
    if (_database != null) return _database;

    // If database don't exists, create one
    _database = await initDB();

    return _database;
  }

  initDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'Customer_Info.db');

    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onOpen: (db) {},
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute('CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_DATA('
          'id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,'
          'name TEXT,'
          'img TEXT,'
          'gender TEXT'
          'age INTEGER,'
          'date TEXT,'
          'status TEXT,'
          ')');
    });
  }

  // Insert employee on database
  createCustomer(ListElement newCustomer) async {
    await deleteAllCustomers();
    final db = await database;
    final res = await db.insert('CUSTOMER_DATA', newCustomer.toJson());

    return res;
  }

  // Delete all employees
  Future<int> deleteAllCustomers() async {
    final db = await database;
    final res = await db.rawDelete('DELETE FROM CUSTOMER_DATA');

    return res;
  }

  Future<List<ListElement>> getAllCustomers() async {
    final db = await database;
    final res = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_DATA");

    List<ListElement> list =
        res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((c) => CustomerInfo.fromJson(c)).toList() : [];

    return list;
  }
}
```

Below is the service file I have created which will get the data:

```
import 'dart:convert';



import 'package:flutter/animation.dart';
import 'package:flutterappincablet/podo_file.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'db_provider.dart';

class Services {

  Future<List<ListElement>> getAllCustomers() async {
    var url = "https://5w05g4ddb1.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/profile/listAll";
    final response = await http.get(url);
    Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
    print('nnnnnnnnnn');
    print(map);
    List<dynamic> data = map["list"];
    print('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    print(data);



    return (data as List).map((c) {
      print('Inserting $c');
      DBProvider.db.createCustomer(ListElement.fromJson(c));
    }).toList();
  }


}
```

Below is the screenshot of the error:
[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Are you sure your table has been created properly?
Not sure but I think the comma after the last column (status) might give an issue.
The rest kind of seems correct on first glance.

Comment: I tried correcting as you said,still facing the same issue